Unable to run appimage (Bambu Studio) - New User
This is my first dip into linux and I've hit my first roadblock. The Bambu Studio software for my 3d printer is only available as an appimage. I made it an executable file in properties and it won't run from command line or double click. Tried moving to desktop and same deal. No errors, it just does nothing. Did the chmod a+x command I found and that gave no errors. Still nothing.
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Thanks for any help!

Managed to get it to do something. Had to install FUSE (libfuse2). Now I get this error message:
./Bambu_Studio_linux_ubuntu-v01.09.01.66.AppImage
/tmp/.mount_Bambu_IOvHzX/bin/bambu-studio: error while loading shared libraries: libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

link to software [link]https://github.com/bambulab/BambuStudio/releases

Here's what ended up working:
sudo add-apt-repository -y "deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main"
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev

I had to run the first command a few times because it couldn't resolve their IP address at first.

This is dangerous and might break your system (adds previous release repo to your list of repos)

This worked for me:
sudo apt install libfuse2 libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0

sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.1.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18

